# Bamboo with tSQLt - Failed to parse test result file

Tags: bamboo, tsqlt

First of all I should point out I'm new to Atlassian's Bamboo and continuous integration in general. This is the first project where I've used either.

I've created a raft of unit tests using the tSQLt framework. I've also configured Bamboo to:

- Get a fresh copy of the repository from BitBucket
- Drop & re-create the build DB
- Use Red-Gate SQL Compare to deploy the DB objects from source to the build DB
- Run the tSQLt tests
- Output the results of the tests in XML format to a file called TestResults.xml

I've checked and can confirm that the TestResults.xml file is created.

In Bamboo I then added a JUnit Parser task to consume the contents of this TestResults.xml file. However when that task runs it returns this error:

`Failed to parse test result file`

At first I thought it might have meant that Bamboo could not find the file. I changed the task that created the results file to output a file called TestResults2.xml. When I did that the JUnit Parser returned this error:

`Failing task since test cases were expected but none were found.`

So I'm assuming that the first error message means Bamboo is finding the file, it just can't parse the file.

I have no idea where to start working out what exactly is the problem. Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: can you share the output XML here?

Comment: I don't think the file was found in either case.  Try using the full path just to make sure, with quotes.

Comment: What we did was to create a t4 template to generate code to run the tsqlt tests and assert on the result.  The tsqlt schema is pretty straight forward so to find test results etc isn't hard at all.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but turned out to be weird behavior from bamboo needing file stamps being modified to have visibility of the JUnit file.

In Windows enviornment you just need to add "script task" before the "JUnit task"

```
powershell  (ls *.xml).LastWriteTime = Get-Date
```

**Reference**

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-12768

Answer (score 2):

I have had several cases of this and was able to fix it by removing **single quotes** and **greater than / less than characters** from **test names** inside the *.rb file.

> Example
>
> > test "make sure 'go_to_world' is removed from header and length < 23"
>
> change to remove single quotes and < symbol
>
> > test "make sure go_to_world is removed from header and length less than 23"

Very common are contractions: "won't don't shouldn't", or possessives: "the vessel's data".

And also **< or >** characters.

I think there is a bug in the parser that just doesn't escape those characters in a test title appropriately.